How to constraint a type parameter to be an `enum` and get the number of cases of the enum represented by it, in scala3?
I want to create an enum map collection similar to java.util.EnumMap but in scala 3.4.
Something like this:
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class EnumMap[K <: scala.reflect.Enum, V](using ctV: ClassTag[V]) {
    val capacity: Int = ??? // How to get the number of cases of the enum represented by K?

    private val backingArray: Array[V] = ctV.newArray(capacity);

    def get(k: K): V = backingArray(k.ordinal);

    def put(k: K, v: V): Unit = backingArray(k.ordinal) = v;
}

And I faced two problems:

How to constraint the type parameter K to accept only enum enumerations and not their cases also? Such that it accepts Color but not Color.red.type.
How to obtain the number of cases corresponding to the enumeration represented by K without using runtime operations. If I am correct, the compiler has all the information needed.


Something like this?
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class EnumMap[K: EnumMap.Ordinals, V: ClassTag] {
  val capacity: Int = summon[EnumMap.Ordinals[K]].size

  private val backingArray: Array[V] =
    summon[ClassTag[V]].newArray(capacity)

  def get(k: K): V = 
    backingArray(summon[EnumMap.Ordinals[K]].ordinal(k))

  def put(k: K, v: V): Unit =
    backingArray(summon[EnumMap.Ordinals[K]].ordinal(k)) = v
}
object EnumMap {

  trait Ordinals[K] {

    def size: Int

    def ordinal(key: K): Int
  }

  // SumOf makes sure it's an enum...
  inline given [K](using k: scala.deriving.Mirror.SumOf[K]): Ordinals[K] =
    new Ordinals[K] {

      // ...and ValueOf ensures that all its its valies are
      // parameterless (case Baz(a: Int) would not work)
      def size: Int = scala.compiletime
        .summonAll[Tuple.Map[k.MirroredElemTypes, ValueOf]]
        .productArity

      def ordinal(key: K): Int = k.ordinal(key)
    }
}


enum Foo:
  case Bar, Baz

val map = new EnumMap[Foo, String]

map.put(Foo.Bar, "test")
map.get(Foo.Bar)

(Scastie)
BTW, this is rather non-idiomatic, get should return Option rather than throw, and this would a bit more work to make it work with other collections (like implementing to, some Factory[(K, V), EnumMap[K, V]]) and with for comprehension (map, flatMap, foreach). But I understand it's just a minimized example.

Yes, it was a minimized example to focus on what I was unable to solve. My final intention is that the collection be immutable and that it supports the iterator, filter and map methods. But that are things easy to do after your contribution. Thank you a lot!

Mateusz, could you give me a link of the name of a book that teaches the metaprogramming you used here?

Start with a https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/derivation.html then there are some blog posts, presentations and reading library code on "type class derivation" - in my case it's a cumulative knowledge from several years of library development, maybe one day I'll be some time to write down all of that in one blog post.

Shouldn't the ValueOf be somehow in a second context parameter list of the inline given? Or being in the body of generated Ordinals instance is enough to reject sum types whose instances aren't all singletons?

Inline works as if you copy-pasted he code at the call site - the signature tells the compiler whether or not it should try to do it, once it decides it should , summonAll will try to summon implicit for every type in the tuple. And since the code is "copy pasted" it will be able to find them without passing them as arguments.

Of course, it's only possible in inline given/def - remove inline and it's will fails as your are expecting.

@MateuzKubuszok Maybe it will be clearer with an example:
sealed trait Sex;
case object Male extends Sex;
case class Female(isReal: Boolean) extends Sex;

val mapInt = new EnumMap[Int, String];
val mapSex = new EnumMap[Sex, String];

The first (mapInt) fails at the signature as intended. But the second (mapSex) fails in the constructor body.

ValueOf only summons singleton types, you cannot summon a record that takes arguments, like enum with parametrized cases, and use them as a single value/index in an EnumMap.

Yes, but in your solution the ValueOf is part of the body of the constructor, and It should be part of the signature in order to satisfy what you said: "the signature tells the compiler whether or not it should try to do it, once it decides it should" :)

Yes. So you put Mirror.SumOf there, let compiler attempt to summon ValueOf for all subtypes, and fail if any of them takes parameters. If you have an enum with only parameterless values - it succeeds. If at least one isn't it fails with a compilation error, as it should, because you cannot have an EnumMap for something like enum Foo { case Bar(i: Int) }. If you don't like lack of ValueOf as error message, you can put @implicitNotFound on Ordinals with a custom message.

Here is another approach that uses a match type instead of a type class to obtain the enum type information.
Also, has an extra feature not asked in the question: the EnumMap knows the instances of the enum (keysDomain) which are required for methods like keySet (not included here).
import scala.annotation.implicitNotFound
import scala.deriving.Mirror.SumOf
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class EnumMap[K <: scala.reflect.Enum, V](
    val keysDomain: IArray[K],
    private val populatedSlots: Array[Boolean],
    private val values: Array[V],
    private val defaultValue: V
) {
    def capacity: Int = values.length

    def apply(k: K): V = values(k.ordinal);

    def get(k: K): Option[V] =
        if populatedSlots(k.ordinal) then Some(values(k.ordinal))
        else None

    def put(k: K, v: V): Unit = {
        values(k.ordinal) = v
        populatedSlots(k.ordinal) = true
    }

    def remove(k: K): Unit = {
        populatedSlots(k.ordinal) = false
        values(k.ordinal) = defaultValue
    }
    
    def size: Int = {
        var accumulator = 0;
        for ps <- populatedSlots do
            if ps then accumulator += 1
        accumulator
    }

    def containsKey(k: K): Boolean = populatedSlots(k.ordinal)
}

object EnumMap {
    inline def newEmpty[K <: scala.reflect.Enum, V](
        using ctV: ClassTag[V], ctK: ClassTag[K],
        @implicitNotFound("`${K}` isn't a sum type") mirror: SumOf[K]
    ): EnumMap[K, V] = {
        val keysTuple = SingleTupleInhabitant.of[mirror.MirroredElemTypes]
        val keyDomain = ctK.newArray(keysTuple.productArity)
        for i <- keyDomain.indices do keyDomain(i) = keysTuple.productElement(i).asInstanceOf[K]
        val newValues = ctV.newArray(keyDomain.length)
        new EnumMap(IArray.unsafeFromArray(keyDomain), new Array(keyDomain.length), newValues, newValues(0))
    }

    @main def test3(): Unit = {
        enum Color {
            case red, green, blue
        }
        val a = EnumMap.newEmpty[Color, String] // ok

        sealed trait Gender(val ordinal: Int) extends scala.reflect.Enum
        case object Male extends Gender(0)
        case class Female(withXChromosome: Boolean) extends Gender(1)

        val r = EnumMap.newEmpty3[Gender, String] // compiler error: All component types should be singletons and `Other` isn't.
    }
}

The keys domain is obtained by means of the SingleTupleInhabitant.of method which is identical to scala.ValueOf but for tuples.
import scala.compiletime.{erasedValue, error, summonFrom}
import scala.deriving.Mirror.SumOf

object SingleTupleInhabitant {

    inline def of[T <: Tuple]: T = summonFrom {
        case _: (TupleMatch[T] =:= T) => loop[T]
    }

    private type TupleMatch[T <: Tuple] <: Tuple = T match {
        case EmptyTuple.type => EmptyTuple.type
        case h *: t => h *: TupleMatch[t]
    }

    private inline def loop[E <: Tuple]: TupleMatch[E] = {
        inline erasedValue[E] match {
            case _: EmptyTuple.type =>
                EmptyTuple
            case _: (h *: t) =>
                summonFrom {
                    case voh: ValueOf[`h`] => voh.value *: loop[t]
                    case _ => error("All component types should be singletons.")
                }
        }
    }
}

The SingleTupleInhabitant class's development comes from the response to another question I posted
I haven't changed the acepted answer to this one because Mateusz deserves all the credits. I couldn't have solved this without his and @DmytroMitin help. Thank you a lot.
